# Jumping to function start from within certain code part

Tags: c++, algorithm, loops, goto

```
include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int Solution(int i_start, int j_start, int i_end, int j_end, int s)
{

    int row_dif=i_start-i_end;
    int col_dif=j_start-j_end;

    while (col_dif !=0 )
    {
        row_dif=i_start-i_end;
        col_dif=j_start-j_end;
        if ((row_dif>0) && (col_dif>0))
        {
            i_start=i_start-2;
            j_start--;
        }
        if ((row_dif>0)) && (col_dif<0)
        {
            i_start=i_start-2;
            j_start++;
        }
        if ((row_dif<0) && (col_dif>0 ))
        {
            i_start=i_start+2;
            j_start--;
        }
        if ((row_dif<0) && (col_dif<0))
        {
            i_start=i_start+2;
            j_start++;
        }
        if (row_dif=0)
        {
            if (col_dif>0)
            {
                j_start-2; 
            }
                else if (col_dif<0)
                {
                    j_start+2; 
                }
                    else  //row_dif=0 dhe col_dif=0
                        {
                            cout<<"Problem solved "<<endl;
                        }
        }
    }
    // col_dif=0
    if (row_dif<=-4)
    {
        i_start=i_start+2;
        j_start++;

    }
    if (row_dif>=4)
    {
        i_start=i_start-2;
        j_start--;

    }

}
```

I am trying to solve Red Knight shortest path with my own method but I am stuck at a part where I need to jump to function start. as an entry-condition I have decided to use `row_dif=0` but when `row_dif` does reach 0 value, I also need to check if there could be more moves (`row_dif>=4` or `row_dif<=-4`) available. And if there are available moves I need to jump to while loop again.

Comment: What about another `while` around?

Comment: @klutt doesnt matter, its an algorithm problem not language problem i think

Comment: Ever heard of the `continue` or `break` statements? One of them could be used to go back to the start of a loop. Use carefully as it tends to create [spaghetti code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code) (though it's *much* better than other ways to *go to* places in the code).

Comment: @EugeneSh. which entry condition should i use?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i have. Not sure where to use them in my case tbh. I have been working on these the past 2hours and I might have lost the plot

Comment: It's made hard to follow by replicating code in `if` code blocks with compound tests. It looks like they can be simplified. Is the real problem the code structure, and not how to defeat it? There is a possible problem too with, for example, `i_start=i_start-2;` where you don't check for underflow.

Comment: @WeatherVane actually if you are familiar with red knight shortest path, it does require certain amount of "If-s". It might be simplified but that's not my main problem right now.

Comment: What does `if (col_dif>0) { j_start-2; }` do? And the other nearby similar error. I again advise you to revisit the conditionals, which in a previous comment I remarked have redundancy. If you simplify the problem, you simplify the answer too. If you ask a question here, you may not get the direct answer you wanted.

Comment: @WeatherVane checks if there can be moves to the left or to the right (the other statement)

Comment: `if (row_dif=0)` this is assignment, read your compiler warnings!

Comment: Is this `if ((row_dif>0)) && (col_dif<0)` a typo?

Comment: @Slava I havent complied it yet, because I havent solved the problem yet.

Comment: @TormundGiantsbane its used to decide which path should we follow as there are 6 possible paths (Upper left, upper right, right, lower right, lower left, left). And all If statements are used to decide what path should we follow

Comment: @AlbanianGeek I'm looking at the parenthesis.. `if ((row_dif>0)) && (col_dif<0)`->`if ((row_dif>0) && (col_dif<0))` You should compile it and fix the errors, get a small working program that you can test and go from there

Comment: I do know how a knight moves and have solved knight problems. Please get the code right, and *then* look at how it can be more efficient.

Comment: @WeatherVane thanks for the advice, should look again but i am determined to solved it tonight

Comment: Your solution needs a loop. Once you add a loop, using `continue` or `break` will become trivial.

Comment: So please go through the comments and fix the bugs that have been pointed out.

Comment: @SergeyA that's what i was going to try, thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

> I am stuck at a part where I need to jump to function start

It seems to me like you are stumbling onto the idea of a recursive function. Something along the lines of

```
return Solution(i_start - 2, j_start - 1, i_end, j_end, s + 1)
```

Recursion causes the state to be pushed onto the program stack.  This idea of a stack is important.

---

The [Red Knight Shortest Path challenge](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/world-codesprint-12/challenges/red-knights-shortest-path) looks to me an awful lot pathfinding.  Specifically, A* pathfinding with constrained movements.

The recursive approach uses a stack and is [depth-first](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search).  For a solution where you want to minimize moves, you want to use a [breadth-first](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) approach.  You will still wind up using a stack, but your primary structure will be a queue.

As this challenge seems to be geared towards search algorithms, I would suggest studying up on everything I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You should write a function `int sign( int i )` that returns -1, 0 or +1 for integer less than, equal to or bigger than zero. Then all of your code becomes:

```
if( row_dif == 0 && col_dif == 0 ) {
   // done interrupt
}
i_start -= 2 * sign( row_dif );
j_start -= 1 * sign( col_dif );
```

plus this code handles situation when `col_dif` is equal to 0, but `row_dif` is not, which you did not in your code.

To add your condition change your loop to:

```
while( true ) {
    row_dif=i_start-i_end;
    col_dif=j_start-j_end;
    if( col_dif == 0 ) {
        if( row_dif == 0 ) {
           // done
           break;
        }
        if( std::abs( row_dif ) < 4 )
            break; // does not look right but follows your logic
        col_dif = sign( row_dif );
    }
    i_start -= 2 * sign( row_dif );
    j_start -= 1 * sign( col_dif );
}
```

Note: comparation operator in C++ is `==` not `=` and this is common mistake for novice C++ programmers.